# How to access route having request params in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am very new in `Node.js` . I have am facing a problem to access various routes. I have three get routes in my `node.js` application `getAllBooks`, `getSingleBookByParams`,and `getSingleBookByQuery`. And my three  endPoints  are   to `getAllBooks http://localhost:9000/` for `getSingleBookByParams http://localhost:9000/123` for `getSingleBookByQuery http://localhost:9000/?id=123`. The problem that i am facing rightnow is ,when hitting this endpoint `http://localhost:9000/?id=123`.I am getting the result of `getAllBooks` route. How can i solve this problem

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, these 2 routes point to the same location:

```
http://localhost:9000/?id=123
```

and

```
 http://localhost:9000/
```

Because querystring (everything after `?`) will not be taken into account for routing. They are `parameters`. You have to change one of the 2 routes OR handle the specific case if an `id` is sent in `query`.

Example on how to handle it for `getSingleBookQueryunder` `http://localhost:9000/?id=123`

```js
// handles this => http://localhost:9000/?id=123
// does not handle this => http://localhost:9000/
app.on('/', (req,res, next) => {
   if(!req.params.id) { 
       // NO id present, so pass to next handler.
       next()
       return
   }
   // Rest of getSingleBookQuery  here!
   // ...
})


// Add the "getAllBook" route here
// ...
```

Make sure, to register `getSingleBookQuery` before the `getAllBooks`.